# CSS table formatting irregularities

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am working to replace a Span based table formatting approach with tables, and I am 90% there.
Given this CSS

```css
table.px_update {
  border-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  margin-left: 2em;
  overflow: scroll;
  padding: 0;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 50em;
}

table.px_update th {
  border-style: none none solid none;
  padding: 0;
}

table.px_update td {
  border-style: none;
  padding: .5em 0 0 0;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;
}

table.px_update col.px_update_num {
  width: 9em;
}

table.px_update col.px_update_date {
  width: 5em;
}

table.px_update col.px_update_version {
  width: 5em;
}

table.px_update col.px_update_note {
  width: 30em;
}
```

```html
<table class="px_update">
  <colgroup>
    <col class="px_update_num">
    <col class="px_update_date">
    <col class="px_update_version">
    <col class="px_update_note">
  </colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>NUMBER</th>
      <th>DATE</th>
      <th>VERSION</th>
      <th>Notes</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>RVT 2019.1</td>
      <td>31.10.2018</td>
      <td>2019.1.122</td>
      <td>1, 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Everything is grand with two exceptions.

1. While both the Date and Version columns are set to the same width, with the Notes column being much wider, the display actually shows Date and Notes as narrow columns, and Version much wider. When I tried removing the width for Notes, but specifically setting width for Version, the result is Version and Notes being equally spaced. Seems odd.
2. If I shrink the browser window down enough, the table gets clipped with no scrolling. I tried `overflow:scroll!important;` on the table with no change. My guess is the Wordpress theme CSS is causing the issue? Or am I not understanding overflow correctly?

And, as a side note/question, how does one get Run Code Snippet for HTML? It seems to be a stack overflow feature, not a link to an external site, but I don't see how to do it? Maybe only available as an edit by the high reputation formatting overlords?

EDIT: Worth noting that I have some inherited CSS on my end, so my headers are left justified. If the headers here where left justified it would look exactly as I want, so it seems there is something in the inherited CSS causing my issue. Hopefully someone has an idea of what.

EDIT #2: So, inspecting elements shows that the Version column is actually way too wide, and it's greyed out in the Safari inspector. Width of the Date column is 75px, while Version is 232 and change. Switching from Computed to Styles I don't see anything that accounts for it. And very odd that the previous columns are fine.

EDIT #3: Made a page with just the current working HTML on it [here](https://www.pragmaticpraxis.com/table-issues/). Hope that allows review of the inherited CSS. I feel like this is SOOOO CLOSE.

Comment: You could also press ctrl + m

Comment: It is working fine in the snippet runner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, as you guessed, the extra CSS in the file wp-custom-css.css. In line 840 we see

```css
.px_update_date {
  display: inline-block; 
  position: absolute; left: 7em; 
}
```

So your second `<col>` does no longer qualify as a table column, no longer having its default display value of `table-column`. Solution: change its class to another name, that is not in use yet.

The answer to your second question is, tables don 't scroll easily. By far the most straightforward solution is to put the table in a container and let the container scroll.

```css
.scrollable {overflow:auto;}
```

```html
<div class="scrollable">

  <table style="width:200%; border:3px outset">
    <tr> <td>Very</td><td>wide</td><td>table</td> </tr>
  </table>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, tried doing that with both a Section and a Div, with a single wrapper for both tables and each table in its own wrapper. Now my tables are side by side! But the scrolling works! ;)

Comment: As for seeing all the CSS, how can that even be done? The WP theme has a ton of stuff, so beyond a public page and inspecting elements, I'm not sure how I could even expose that?

Comment: on the scrolling I have it working. I reused a container I already had, and something there broke things. Made a new container that just scrolls, and that's working. So I should be able to consolidate now and get the functionality I need. Now, those funky column widths....

Comment: Well, you have to know what to look for in the rules. When I could see your example page, inspecting the table rows to find problems was easy. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewm26.jpg

Comment: Ah, it's because I am not being discrete enough in my types! Off to fix and test.